# How to use sshuttle to connect to an aws service via two hops?

Tags: amazon-web-services, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have following situation:

1. Host A: My Machine
2. Host B: AWS Bastion Host
3. Host C: EC2 instance in a AWS VPC with a private IP only
4. Host D: AWS Elasticsearch Service, accessible only from Host C via endpoint name `https://<id>.<region>.es.amazonaws.com`

At the moment I do the following to access data on Elasticsearch instance

1. ssh to bastion
2. ssh to Host C
3. `curl https://<id>.<region>.es.amazonaws.com`

How could I use [sshuttle](https://sshuttle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) or ssh port-forwarding to curl Elasticsearch from Host A (my machine)?